# table columns have values but after execute SELECT * FROM t_order , the some of the return result are null

Tags: mysql, mybatis

There are values in some of columns in the table, but when use select sql sentence in mybatis, most of columns return values are null.

tried similar sql sentence in mysql(Navicat) it shows all the values correctly.

mapper file as below:

```
<select id="queryPageInDao" resultType="TOrder">
    SELECT * FROM t_order
    <trim prefix="WHERE " prefixOverrides="AND |OR "> 
        AND del = 0
    <if test="param1.userId != null" >
            AND  user_id = #{param1.userId,jdbcType=INTEGER}
        </if>
        <if test="param1.courseId != null" >
            AND course_id = #{param1.courseId,jdbcType=INTEGER}
        </if>
        <if test="param1.paystatus != null" >
            AND    paystatus = #{param1.paystatus,jdbcType=INTEGER}
        </if>
       <if test="param1.userEmail != null">
           AND    user_email like CONCAT('%',#{param1.userEmail},'%' ) 
       </if>
    </trim>
    <if test="param2.sortField != null and param2.sortField != ''">
        ORDER BY ${param2.sortField}  ${param2.sortDirection}
    </if>
    LIMIT #{param2.startIndex, jdbcType=INTEGER} , #{param2.pageSize, jdbcType=INTEGER} 
    </select>
```

return result as below:

> [TOrder [id=38, userId=null, courseId=null, price=10.01, paystatus=0, ... del=0],

Data in table as below:

```
id     userId   courseId   price       del
38        45      44       10.01        0
```

expecting something like this

> [TOrder [id=38, userId=45, courseId=44, price=10.01, .......

Comment: I think you just need to enable `mapUnderscoreToCamelCase` in the config. If that is not the case, provide an [executable example](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and I may be able to help.

Comment: Please show `t_order` table definition and `TOrder` class definition.